# How to find out a contact request is accepted or rejected in XMPP?

Tags: xmpp, smack

I am using smack API to accept or reject the contact request sent to a user.
Before I render the client (my product has a notification system and I create a notification to the user when he/she is added to somebody's roster), I would like to know the status of the subscription request. So that I can show accept/reject buttons for the user to act upon and if the action already happened would render saying "You have already accepted/rejected" kind of a message.

I understand that if user A had received a request from B and if A accepts the request then the subscription status of the roster entry becomes FROM or BOTH.
But how can I figure out whether I have rejected a subscription request from a certain user?

Answer (score 0):

To listen if user has rejected your add buddy request. You need to register a PacketListener with filtering of packets of Presence class. In it you will get an presence packet of type unsubscribed from the user, who has rejected the request.

```
public class RequestListener implements PacketListener {
    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet pack) {
        Presence pres = (Presence) pack;
        if (pres.getType() != null && 
                     pres.getType().equals(Presence.Type.unsubscribed)) {
            // user with jid pres.getFrom() rejected your request.
        }
    }
}

// somewhere in code to register the request listener after login
connection.addPacketListener(new RequestListener(), 
      new PacketTypeFilter(Presence.class));
```